# ImageView shows white space at top and bottom of image

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I am adding image in android layout. There is no white space in the image at top and bottom but when i add image in imageView it shows white space at top and bottom of image.
Hence if i want to add textview immediately below the image space appears between image and textview.

I don't understand  why `imageview` is showing white space at top and bottom of the image. I have not added anything like `android:padding` etc.

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/img1" />
```

Comment: lookup scaletypes for imageviews

Answer (score 26, accepted):

add these `attributes` into that `ImageView`

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:cropToPadding="false"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: Good answer. By default android:cropToPadding="false" attribute will be false. So no need to add this line.

Comment: I am using Google maps static api to set map to an imageview, but I was facing large height imageview problem. Thanks for `adjustViewBounds` tip.

Answer (score 5):

change to this

```
   <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageView3"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:adjustViewBounds="true"
   android:scaleType="fitXY"
   android:src="@drawable/img1" />
```